# How to configure app settings in CI/CD pipelines using azure tfs

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am try to create an CI/CD pipeline using azure tfs. I have successfully build and deployed pipeline using IIS web deployment utility. But now, I want to deploy asp.net app to local on-premise machine. But during build or release, I want to configure app settings, so that I can choose the connection strings and server locations. I followed a lot of tutorials on Microsoft website and other like [this](https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/azure-app-service-settings-from-azure-devops/)
But, there is a problem, it asks for azure subscription. Do I need it in my case? Is there any alternative approach or some tutorial I can follow to do such deployment?

I do have a basic plan subscription, but I am haven't figured put how much azure app service utility will cost?

Can someone guide me, if I am in right direction or share some resource I could follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your question, you need to use IIS Web App Deploy task, so you do not need azure subscription. You can use the `File Transforms & Variable Substitution` function that comes with `IIS Web App Deploy` to configure connection strings and server locations through `XML transformation` or `XML variable substitution`. For details ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic).

[image]

Or you can try to use [File Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops) task .